# How to start with Rails API Design and implementation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, ruby-on-rails-3.2, api-design

i am new to Rails API implementation. Is there any blog/site/book/tutorial with i can start off implementing rails API implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you want to also remember, apart from the other answer, is an API is just a [series of endpoints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_endpoint) - allowing you to send requests to the endpoints & receive responses.

What you'll typically find from the gems & other information is that an API in rails is essentially a namespaced controller -

--

In reference to the [RailsCast on this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning), you'll find this code:

```
#app/controllers/api/v1/products_controller.rb
module Api
  module V1
    class ProductsController < ApplicationController
      class Product < ::Product
        # Note: this does not take into consideration the create/update actions for changing released_on
        def as_json(options = {})
          super.merge(released_on: released_at.to_date)
        end
      end

      respond_to :json

      def index
        respond_with Product.all
      end

      def show
        respond_with Product.find(params[:id])
      end

      def create
        respond_with Product.create(params[:product])
      end

      def update
        respond_with Product.update(params[:id], params[:product])
      end

      def destroy
        respond_with Product.destroy(params[:id])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As rails is just a series of `modules` & `classes`, an API will basically be a way for you to create a module to store your `API` controller class inside.

The supporting routes for this would include (as per the Railscast):

```
 #config/routes.rb
 namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1) do
      resources :products, :other, :controllers
    end
  end
```

As you can see, the routes literally just allow you to send `json` requests to your scoped API controller. The endpoints would therefore become:

```
#api/v1/products
#api/v1/other
#api/v1/controllers
```

--

So bottom line is an API is more about determining which data you wish to send (and receive) as it is how to set up the system

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty nice easy-to-use gem to build rails api's called rails-api, you may check it out, it's pretty well documented.

https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api

Comment: Unfortunately, it has bad community support.

Comment: Also a nice RailsCast on it: [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem)